# How to read active ip connection command

Tags: linux, putty

Can you tell me what the 937 is?  Forgive me I'm new to Linux and I don't know where to start looking.

When I run:

```
$ netstat -ntu | awk '{print $5}' | cut -d: -f1 | sort | uniq -c | sort -n 

  1 108.213.8.218
  1 24.140.138.250
  1 24.140.83.106
  1 41.252.156.89
  1 75.98.227.206
  1 Address
  1 servers)
  2 127.0.0.1
  2 24.74.92.171
  2 75.187.161.70
  3 70.60.165.100
  3 99.164.109.143
  6 24.140.153.22
937
```

Comment: Run the command with each of the piped commands removed e.g "netstat -ntu | awk '{print $5}' | cut -d: -f1 | sort | uniq -c " then "netstat -ntu | awk '{print $5}' | cut -d: -f1 | sort" etc. and that should throw some light on it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are IPv6 addresses (field 5) of the form ::1:33766 so with a delimiter of ":" the first field is "". There are 937 lines that have an IPv6 address.

Edit: See [Wikipedia page describing shortening of IPv6 addresses](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6_address#Presentation) for more information.